# gcc not finding cc1 for mingw on cygwin under Emacs

Tags: shell, gcc, emacs, path, cygwin

Ok, so long title... I have switched out my Mingw Emacs for the Cygwin emacs-w32 but have run into some challenging path(?) issue.

I compile using i686-w64-mingw32-gcc (previously known as -mno-cygwin).

In a normal terminal I get:

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc exp.c -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/32gcc/mingw64-i686-gcc-4.8.2-1/src/gcc-4.8.2/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/32gcc/mingw64-i686-gcc-4.8.2-1/src/gcc-4.8.2 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib --datarootdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/mingw64-i686-gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/mingw64-i686-gcc/html -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-sysroot=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root --with-build-sysroot=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root --disable-multilib --disable-win32-registry --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-dwarf2 --enable-decimal-float=bid --enable-lto
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/cc1.exe -quiet -v -U_REENTRANT exp.c -quiet -dumpbase exp.c -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -auxbase exp -version -o /tmp/cc6glCby.s
```

So that works. Note the path prepended to the cc1.exe. Which seems a reasonable place for it to be.

I have tried to set up emacs-w32 to have the same paths. Echoing the $PATH in the terminal and the output from M-x shell-command "echo $PATH" in emacs gives the same result. As far as I can tell it has a working path, all commands that I try, including 'ls', 'make' as well as some local ones, work as expected, even inside a Makefile. Except for the i686-w64-mingw-gcc, which does this:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/32gcc/mingw64-i686-gcc-4.8.2-1/src/gcc-4.8.2/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/32gcc/mingw64-i686-gcc-4.8.2-1/src/gcc-4.8.2 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib --datarootdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/mingw64-i686-gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/mingw64-i686-gcc/html -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-sysroot=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root --with-build-sysroot=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root --disable-multilib --disable-win32-registry --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-dwarf2 --enable-decimal-float=bid --enable-lto
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 cc1 -quiet -v -iprefix /bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/ -U_REENTRANT exp.c -quiet -dumpbase exp.c -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -auxbase exp -version -o /cygdrive/c/Users/Thomas/AppData/Local/Temp/ccC472Qu.s
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc: error: spawn: No such file or directory
```

So the only difference is that this time the gcc-wrapper doesn't put a path before the cc1, presumably because it fails to find it in some path that it expects it to be.

But it also doesn't print any COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER, whatever that means...

This happens inside a makefile and in a M-x shell-command. It does not happen in an interactive shell like M-x shell. So it smells like a interactive/non-interactive issue.

But since the paths are identical, I am at a loss. Anyone with *any* ideas?

Primary suspect at this point: COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER, why doesn't the non-interactive version print that?

Comment: I have compiled with `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc test.c -v` and do not see that problem. The content of the shell script is: 1st line: `#!/usr/bin/bash` 2nd line: `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc test.c -v`. gcc is also 4.8.2 (same configuration).

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand. What shell script? Also, I am not necessarily saying there is a problem, as in a bug. *I* have a problem and I don't know where to start looking. I was looking for aid, or someone pointing out something I have missed or misunderstood.

Comment: I'm trying to help solving your problem. You wrote that the problem occurs with Makefiles and shell-commands. I interpreted shell-command as shell script since starting gcc as command gives the expected result. I wrote a shell script with two relevant lines (and of course a finishing newline). I didn't want to write an answer yet. Formatting is very restricted in comments. Therefore, I wrote what the content of the two relevant lines in the shell script is. Is your first line also `#!/usr/bin/bash`? It may be that I misunderstood the meaning of shell-command in your question.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have clarified that I mean the Emacs M-x shell-command, not a shell script. The second output is from executing the compilation command in that, while the first is from entering it in an Emacs interactive shell started with M-x shell. This is the same output as the one I get when I run the compilation command in a terminal. But since the problem occurs when doing M-x compile which runs make too, I can't use Emacs as I used to...

Comment: Please, look what the following commands deliver: `M-: explicit-shell-file-name`, `M-: (get-env "ESHELL")`, `M-: shell-file-name`. These are the variables/commands that determine which shell to use for `M-x shell` (in that order) while `shell-command` only uses `M-: shell-file-name`.

Comment: You mean (getenv "SHELL")? All three give "bash" (except (getenv "ESHELL") which gives nil, since I'm not using ESHELL. I've also edited the question to point to my current lead (COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER) and why that wouldn't be used by the Emacs non-interactive invocation of the same gcc.

Comment: The `COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER` is a harmless optimization tool. That this tool and `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` cannot be found is the actual problem. `~/.bashrc` is not sourced by `M-x shell-command` maybe that makes the difference. Could you try `M-x shell-command` and then `source ~/.bashrc; i686-w64-mingw32-gcc exp.c -v` to see whether this works?

Comment: Thanks for the continued discussion, Tobias. I too realized that the "not finding" was the issue and pursued this and finally found the problem to be a tiny difference in the PATHs. I'll rework the question to make the significant parts more obvious, so that an answer can be written. Thanks again!